# match data in two notepads

Tags: html, match, notepad, ctrl

I have two notepads and each notepad contains some data. Let's say Notepad 1 and Notepad 2

`Notepad 1 contains: A, B, C`

`Notepad 2 contains: C, D, E`

I want to ask that **how can i find data in Notepad 2 that contains notepad 1 data**. Here answer is `C`. But i have lots of data in notepad 1 and notepad2. It is not possible to take individual data from notepad 1 and to press Ctrl+F in notepad 2 to find data. Is there any suitable method for this? Will it be possible by converting these notepads into `html pages`?

Comment: by notepads, you mean text files?

Comment: I do not think this is programming related in any way.

Comment: if any solution exists please let me know, can it be achievable by javascript in web pages?

Comment: Javascript can not open text files.

Comment: @Max okay but is there any possible way to find out the solution in web pages, i am saying that if there are two html pages then any solution?

Comment: Not sure if troll or just ignorant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you'd like to have a look on diff/merge tools. [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is a free one. Another good option is [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/), it is commercial. Also you can just use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) editor with its [Compare plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/). These tools are GUI based and can help you if you want to see and edit difference.

If you need to extract and somehow automatically process difference, you more likely will have to use some console tools and scripting. *nix `diff` command can be used to extract difference and there are a lot of scripting languages suitable for text processing: sed, AWK, Perl, Python for instance.

Comment: I don't know because it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you just want to see the difference then it will work. If you want to extract difference and process it in some way, you'll need to use some console tools like diff and probably sed and/or AWK (on *nix).

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with the `comm(1)` tool:

```
$ cat F1
A
B
C
$ cat F2
C
D
E
$ comm -12 F1 F2
C
$
```

The `-1` suppresses all lines unique to the first file. `-2` suppresses all lines unique to the second file. All that is left is lines common to both.